# White strip over an image?

Tags: css, html

So i have a background image, i need to put an horizontal white strip over this background image, in order to put a title into the strip. I know how to make boxes over an image on CSS but i'm having an hard time making this strip, it must not be a box, it has to cover the whole background image from the left margin to the right margin of the image, any idea?

Here is the piece of code involved:

```css
.title-image {
  position: fixed;
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

h1 {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Play;
  color: #c76161;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <img class="title-image" src="" alt="">
  <h1>Title</h1>      
</div>
```

Comment: If you're trying to make a Watermark that won't protect your stuff, since the file is still available to the Client, via URL.

Comment: Please also provide the HTML

Comment: @PHPglue no watermark, just a university assignment :)

Comment: added HTML @OliverBaumann

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use flexboxes and background images

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.title_container{
  width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><div class="title_container"><h1 class="title">Test</h1></div></div>
```

Replace background-color: red; by background-image: url("yourimage.png");

Comment: i dont see the need of flexbox

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use multiple background like this:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  line-height:200px;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background:
  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.8),rgba(255,255,255,0.8))0 50%/100% 80px  no-repeat,
  url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200/);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>
```